# File Level Checkin Access in Team Foundation server 2013

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am new to TFS.
How to give file level **Check in** access to the user or user group in TFS 2013?

For example, my ASP.NET MVC project has around 50 `.cs` files and for the contributer "someone" I want to give the **Check in** access to only 10 files.

Is this possible in TFS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question "is this possible?"

Yup it is very much possible in TFS to control the access rights at the file level. But it can be a painful process depending on how those 10 files are located within your folder structure. If you manage the access rights to TFS at individual user level (not using AD groups) then I would advice you to define new TFS groups and classify users based on their check-in rights and this way it will easier for you to manage.

Let me know if you need any clarification.

Edit: Screenshots added

1. Right click the file -> Advanced -> Security

[image]

1. Now within each group (Contributor, Builder etc), you can define the check-in/checkout rights.

[image]

Comment: I have those files in different folders. can you please explain on how to give file level check in rights . thank you

Comment: Check the updated answer. Mark it as the answer if it solved your issue.